# MySQL - insert data from another table merged with constants

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have a temporary table (products_temp) with some data, and I have another table (products) I need to insert the data into. I have some constants I need to set manually on new records, like vendor_id=1, etc...

Is it possible to do the insertion with the temporary table data and the constants in one request?

temp_products:

```
product_name | product_desc | category_name | mf_name ...
```

products (category_name, mf_name is not in):

```
product_id | product_name | product_desc | vendor_id | distributor_id ...
```

constants:

```
vendor_id=1, distributor_id=2
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use an [`INSERT ... SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) where you are selecting constant values as well as data from `products_temp`:

```
INSERT INTO products (product_data, vendor_id)
    SELECT data, '1' FROM products_temp
```

Comment: genius! didn't think about that